# Validação de data composta por três inteiros no Django

Tags: python-3.x, validação, data, django-2.0

Na minha aplicação estou recebendo do usuário o dia, mês e ano, os três campos fazem parte de um *form* e são `IntegerField`. Não quero utilizar o `DateField`, pois o usuário tem as opções de informa:

1. Ano;
2. Ano e mês;
3. Ano, mês e dia;

Minha ideia é, após o usuário informar os dados, validar os mesmos chamando a função `valida_data` (criada por mim):

```
erro = form.valida_data()
```

Função `valida_data` criada no `form`:

```
def valida_data(self):
   if self.fields['mes'] == 2 or 4 or 5 or 6:
      pass
```

Porém ocorre erro, pois estou comparando um `IntegerField` com um `int()`.

Conseguem me ajudar na criação da função de validação de dia, mês e ano? Sabem outra maneira de realizar a validação?

Comment: Essa sua condição `if self.fields['mes'] == 2 or 4 or 5 or 6`, não faz sentido. O correto, aparentemente, seria `if self.fields['mes'] in (2, 4, 6)`. Aliás, qual é o erro que dá?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quer verificar se a data inserida é ou não válida? Use o módulo **datetime** que sabe como fazê-lo coretamente:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date

def valida_data(ano, mes=1, dia=1):
    """ Valida uma data qualquer, recebe `dia`, `mes` e `ano` e devolve
    `True` se a data for válida ou `False` em caso contrário. """
    try:
        __ = date(ano, mes, dia)
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Esta é a rotina de testes, para verificar os valores possíveis.

```
def test_valida_data():
    """ Rotina de teste, verifica a função `valida_data()`. """
    # data válida
    assert valida_data(1980, 10, 12) == True
    # data inválida
    assert valida_data(1982, 2 , 31) == False
    # apenas mês e ano
    assert valida_data(1950, 6) == True
    # data inválida apenas com mês e ano
    assert valida_data(1994, 13) == False
    # apenas o ano
    assert valida_data(1973) == True
```

Esta rotina pode ser chamada manualmente com `print(test_valida_data() == None)` (deverá retornar `True` ou gerar uma exceção de `AssertionError`) ou pelo pytest com `pytest valida_data.py`.